# Does this function have a (global) minimum?

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

A good day to everyone.

Does the following function have a (global) minimum:

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} + {\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)}^\theta,~~x\in\mathbb R$$

where

$$\theta = {\displaystyle\frac{3\log 2 - \log 5}{2(\log 5 - 2\log 2)}} > 1?$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%20%28%281%2b%281/x%29%29%2b%281%2b%281/x%29%29%5E%28%283log%202%20-%20log%205%29/%282%2a%28log%205%20-%202log%202%29%29%29%29) says it has none.

Comment: @Babak S., yes $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oops, where did the WolframAlpha link go? :(

Comment: Let me re-paste it here --  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+%28%281%2B%281%2Fx%29%29%2B%281%2B%281%2Fx%29%29^%28%283log+2+-+log+5%29%2F%282*%28log+5+-+2log+2%29%29%29%29

Comment: Did you try to differentiate it?

Comment: WolframAlpha says that the derivative is strictly negative for $x \neq 0$.  So I wonder why it can't find a global minimum?

Comment: Because it is strictly negative. There is the infimum, but no global minimum.

Comment: I see.  So the infimum is 2, but no global minimum?  Ahh yeah, I see Amzoti's answer now.  Thanks Harold and Amzoti!  :)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: You are very welcome. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do some analysis and see if we can convince ourselves that WA is correct.

- A plot of the function (be careful with the imaginary values for $x \lt 0$), shows:

[image]

- We find that we have a limit of $2$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ (of course, we also see this in the plot), but this does not help us. This is our infimum.
- Taking the derivative yields:

$$\displaystyle f'(x) = -\frac{x \ln(8/5) (1/x+1)^{(\ln(8/5)/\ln(25/16))}+2 x \ln(5/4)+2 \ln(5/4)}{2 x^2 (x+1) \ln(5/4)}$$

- If we plot $f'(x)$, we have:

[image]

- The limit of the derivative is zero as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, but this does not help us.
- Analytically or numerically, we can find no value of $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$, that is, we can find no critical points.
- Conclusion, there is no global minimum (or maximum or local ones either).

Comment: Nice graphs! Nice work! Nice green $\checkmark$! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, that function has an UGLY derivative! :-)